# How can i get the particular tag content in xml file even it having multiple same tags by using the batch scripting

Tags: xml, windows, batch-file, cmd

I am creating a batch script to get the telephone number of a particular employee from the xml file. For example consider the below data.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Employee_Info xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="employee.xs">
    <Employee Employee_Number="105">
        <Name>Masashi Okamura</Name>
        <Department>Design Department</Department>
        <Telephone>03-1452-4567</Telephone>
        <Email>okamura@xmltr.co.jp</Email>
    </Employee>
    <Employee  Employee_Number="109">
        <Name>Aiko Tanaka</Name>
        <Department>Sales Department</Department>
        <Telephone>03-6459-98764</Telephone>
        <Email>tanaka@xmltr.co.jp</Email>
    </Employee>
</Employee_Info>
```

Here two employee tags are there, my requirement is to get the particular employee telephone number. that is if we want get the telephone number of a  employee_number 105 it should display 03-1452-4567 only like for 109 also. Kindly any one help me on this.

my script is below but i am getting both the numbers, could any body help me on this.

```
@ECHO Off  
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion    
FOR /f "tokens=2 delims==>" %%a IN ('find /I "Employee_Number" employee.xml') DO(  
set num=%%~nxa  
IF /I "!num!" EQU "105" (  
FOR /f "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%b IN ('find /I "telephone" employee.xml') DO echo %%b )  
)  
echo %ph%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code fail because the second `FOR` command show *all* telephone numbers. You should match the *number of records* that first `FOR` processed until the desired Employee_Number was found, and then use *the same number* of records to show the telephone number in second `FOR`:

```
@ECHO Off  
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion    

set "times1=0"
FOR /f "tokens=2 delims==>" %%a IN ('find /I "Employee_Number" employee.xml') DO (
   set /A times1+=1
   set "num=%%~a"
   IF /I "!num!" EQU "105" (  
      set "times2=0"
      FOR /f "tokens=3 delims=<>" %%b IN ('find /I "telephone" employee.xml') DO (
         set /A times2+=1
         IF !times2! equ !times1! set "ph=%%b"
      ) 
   )  
)
echo %ph%
```

Comment: thank you so much @Aacini. thanks for your help , it working fine and my problem is solved now

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the number of Employee and Telephone tags is identical. My general approach would imply usage of the SKIP option within the FOR command.

FIND all Employee tags, then do a FOR loop for them to FIND the one that has your desired number. After each that was not the one your looking for, increase a variable to count how many you passed until you found the right one.

Now FIND all Telephone tags, FOR loop them, but SKIP the number you figured out in the loop before. In your example that number would be 2:

```
FOR /f "skip=2 tokens=3 delims=<>" %%b IN ('find /I "telephone" employee.xml') DO echo %%b )
```

Answer (score 0):

this accepts a single argument - the file you want to get info from:

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* JScript comment
    @echo off
    cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" %*
    exit /b %errorlevel%

@if (@X)==(@Y) @end JScript comment */

var objDoc = WScript.CreateObject("MSXML.DOMDocument");
objDoc.load(WScript.Arguments.Item(0));

var nodesList = objDoc.selectNodes("//Employee/Telephone");
var nodesList2 = objDoc.selectNodes("//Employee");
for(var i=0;i<nodesList.length;i++){
    WScript.Echo(nodesList2.item(i).getAttribute("Employee_Number")+":"+nodesList.item(i).text);
}
```